# how to get rid of the unwanted top cells of table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, custom-cell

I am using custom cell type `UITableview`.

The custom cell just has two lines of text one below other - key value pair.

The data creating the table is an array sorted based on key.

I need to check whether the top some of the top keys are to be be a part of the table or not.

If not I need to skip the use of those key value pairs and would then use the left array data to create the table. e.g index 0,1,2 may have to be skipped.

When I try to put this condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this

```
if (key is to be used)
{
    cell.key.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mrow1 etimov]];

    cell.value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mvalue1 valor]];
}
```

What this does is that instead of not creating the top 3 cells (say) it creates the cells without actual data of key value but the labels I used in the custom cell for key and value.

What do I change to get rid of the unwanted top cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change number of rows in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Obviously, if you remove three rows, number of rows will change.

It will also affect the `indexPath` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. After skipping first three items, `indexPath.row = 0` should correspond to third item in item array.

In other words:

```
numberOfRows = items.count - numberOfSkippedRows
item = items[indexPath.row + numberOfSkippedRows]
```

Comment: i affected the number of rows and reduced them. but what is happening is that instead of skipping first 3 cells it is not creating the last 3 cells. and still creating the first 3 cells without actual data

Comment: Read carefully about `indexPath` and how to get corresponding item in my answer